# How to write a HelloWorld header files?

Tags: c++, header

I have the following code in a single cpp file (`tested.cpp`):

```
class tested {
        private:
                int x;
        public:
                tested(int x_inp) {
                        x = x_inp;
                }

                int getValue() {
                        return x;
                }
};
```

Now I want to write a header file for this code. How should it look? And what should I change in my cpp file after I have a header file. I supposed that my header file should be something like that:

```
class tested {
   private:
      int x;
   public:
      tested(int x);
      int getValue();
}
```

Then in my cpp file I should `#include "tested.h"`. I also need to replace the whole class by:

```
tested::tested(int c_inp) {
   x = x_inp;
}

tested::getValue(){
   return x;
}
```

Is it right?

Comment: Does it generate any errors or warnings on compilatio or runtime?

Comment: There is no return type in the definition of `getValue` and there's a typo in the constructor parameter name, otherwise yes. But why ask when the compiler can answer this much more quickly?

Comment: "Is it right?" Why don't you try and see ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to type the type of return for methods other than constructor and destructor :

```
int tested::getValue(){
   return x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make your header file more universal, you could use the macro `#ifndef` like it is done here
http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/preprocessor/ifdef.html

Answer (score 1):

Yep, as freude said before, it is usual to protect header files against multiple inclusions with #ifndef (especially in big projects, or if your file may be part of one).

Some other things (essentially matter of style):

- It isn't mandatory to put "private:" for the first members of the class, since all class members are private by default.
- It is usual to put a character before (or after) the name of each attribute of the class (e.g. "x_" instead of "x")